# bsDatepicker is not setting default time in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using bsDatepicker library to get date and time, but if user clicks on date first instead of selecting time then the date picker picks the time automatically when the component was initialized. Is there any solution that I can set default time to it like 12:00 when user did not select time??
the HTML code is ====>>>
`<input placeholder="Datepicker" name="endDate" required class="form-control" [bsConfig]="{withTimepicker: true, dateInputFormat: 'MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss',   showWeekNumbers:false}" bsDatepicker ngModel>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning *initCurrentTime* false ?

Comment: I tried but no luck. `<input
              placeholder="Datepicker"
              name="endDate"
              required
              class="form-control"
              [bsConfig]="{withTimepicker: true, dateInputFormat: 'MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss',showWeekNumbers:false, initCurrentTime: false}"
              bsDatepicker
              ngModel>`

Comment: if we set the initCurrentTime: true then it will pick the current time, not the time when the component was initialized.

Comment: I want a default time to be set automatically if user did not selects time

Comment: and if you set a default value for [bsValue]="bsValue", as you initiate it in the initiation of the component with the specific time (12:00 for example)

Comment: It appears initCurrentTime is a broken setting: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/6317